# How to properly manage the lifecycle of logfiles created with plugins using Java logging with log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

My team is working on a plugin for NetBeans which uses logging to a specified file. The logging system uses SLF4J + Log4J2; the only configuration information that I am aware of is a `log4j2.xml` file with logging properties for the plugin, and the following:

```
    LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext)LogManager.getContext(false);
    loggerContext.reconfigure();
```

(The fact that I am using SLF4J and NetBeans is not really relevant here.)

The question I have, is what is the correct way to start logging when the plugin starts and stop logging when the plugin exits? (The JVM keeps on going with NetBeans so the log files aren't automatically closed.)

I looked up [`LoggerContext`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/LoggerContext.html) and I see `stop()` and `terminate()` methods but I can't find any documentation for how applications are supposed to use `LoggerContext`, so I don't know whether this `LifeCycle` stuff is an internal detail or something that an application is supposed to use.

---

Some more specific details:

Our plugin lifecycle looks something like the diagram below (only one instance is permitted to run at a time). The "A" and "B" refer to log configurations that we would want to have in effect.

```
     [Something starts within the JVM to load log4j classes first.
      It might be our plugin, it might be something else.
A     log4j's default mechanism kicks in to create log configuration A]
|
|    [time passes]
|
|    [our plugin starts]
A    [log4j classes first loaded, 
|    default mechanism kicks in to create log configuration A]
A    setup log configuration B
A B  log event 1
A B  log event 2
A B  log event 3
A    shutdown log configuration B
|    [our plugin exits]
|
|    [time passes]
|
|    [our plugin starts]
A    setup log configuration B
A B  log event 1
A B  log event 2
A B  log event 3
A    shutdown log configuration B
|    [our plugin exits]
|
|    [time passes]
|
     [JVM exits]
```

The configuration A is associated with the JVM and is the default configuration created by log4j the first time it is loaded by the JVM.

Configuration B is managed programmatically by the plugin and should have explicit startup / shutdown independent of configuration A (and configuration A should not be affected).

Is there any way to achieve this with log4j 2.0?

Comment: Are you saying you want to have two log configurations active simultaneously? That is what the diagram looks like with both A and B active during log events 1, 2 and 3...

Comment: Yes. We don't want the plugin to interfere with global logging configuration (e.g. "log all ERROR events to a global log"), but the plugin needs to setup its own context for plugin events.

Answer (score 2):

In Log4j 2.5 you can call Configurator.shutdown().  With Log4j 2.6 you can call LogManager.shutdown().

Comment: But how do I make sure that I shut down only the logging resources that my plugin uses? If NetBeans has logging and/or another plugin uses log4j, I don't want to shut down all of the logging activities, just the ones that I setup for my plugin.

Comment: I'm looking for some "big picture" documentation that tells how to use log4j in a JVM containing multiple cooperating applications such as plugins / servlets / etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can safely use separate `LoggerContext`s for different components of your application.

`terminate()` and `stop()` are absolutely identical. Actually, the former just calls the latter and does nothing more. `terminate()` is a part of the `LoggerContext` own api, while `stop()` is a part of wider `LifeCycle` interface.

If you want to implement separation of your logging contexts properly, use the mechanism of context selectors. Lo4j2 provides the interface `ContextSelector` for classes that are responsible for choosing the context that will be returned by `LogManager.getContext()`. There're several implementations out of the box:

- `BasicContextSelector` choses a context based on the current thread.
- `BundleContextSelector` for using in an OSGI environment.
- `JndiContextSelector` for multiple web applications in a single servlet container.
- `ClassLoaderContextSelector` choses a context based on the caller's class loader.

In order to specify which selector you'd like to use, set the `Log4jContextSelector` Java option.

For instance, if your plugins run in separate threads, you can chose the `BasicContextSelector`:

```
-DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.BasicContextSelector
```

and use separate `LoggerContext`s for you plugins this way (this code must be run in the plugin's thread):

```
// Create a separate context for the plugin
LoggerContext pluginContext = new LoggerContext("PluginContext");

// Setup pluginContext...

// BasicContextSelector uses ContextAnchor.THREAD_CONTEXT
// to bind contexts to threads:
ContextAnchor.THREAD_CONTEXT.set(pluginContext);

// Your plugin works and has access to your logging context
LogManager.getContext(false); // Returns pluginContext

// Stop and remove the plugin's logging context
pluginContext.stop();
ContextAnchor.THREAD_CONTEXT.set(null);
```

Depending on the architecture of your plugins, you can use one of these implementations or provide your own, it's pretty easy, you'll just need to implement the following methods:

- `getContext()` to create new contexts (or return existing ones) based on the parameters provided to `LogManager.getContext(...)`.
- `getLoggerContexts()` to return the collection of the available contexts (the ones you created before).
- `removeContext()` to remove the contexts from memory when they are stopped (terminated).

Comment: does this mean that logging events will go to this new custom context but will no longer go to the default context? Is there a way to have them go to both?

Comment: Events will go to the context that was used to get the logger to which you send those events. Since any logger is owned by a particular context (see architecture here: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/architecture.html), an event will go to only one of the contexts. If needed to send events to two contexts, I would create my own `Logger` that would wrap two loggers: one that was obtained by `getContext(true)` and one obtained by `getContext(false)`. All the logging operations I would delegate to those two loggers.

Comment: A more complex, but a bit more idiomatic solution would be to implement your own `LoggerContext` that would wrap two standard contexts (the plugin's one and the main) and return a described above wrapper around two `Logger`s from `getLogger()`. Then, you can return this custom context from your custom context selector. As the result, the client code will not know about all these wrappers and just use loggers as usual, but all the events will eventually go to both the plugin's and main underlying loggers.

Comment: This chapter on log separation might also be of use for you: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/logsep.html